# Smtp setting error with connection ?! How one the earth Servage.net work D_; ...going to make me mad :D

Tags: javascript, php, css, email, smtp

Every time when i try to connecto to send servage smpt it throw me an error:

```
SMTP connect() failed.
```

I triend with following settings:

```
include('res/mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

include('res/mailer/class.smtp.php');
$msg = new PHPMailer;
$msg->IsSMTP();
$msg->SMTPAuth      = true;
$msg->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; or 'tsl'
$msg->Host          = "smtp1.servage.net"; tried also smtp2.servage.net
$mail->Port         = "465"; tried also 25, 2525, 110
$msg->Username      = ".......@.....com";
$msg->Password      = ".........";
```

There something really strange with another hosting (siteground) i can do it perfectly D: If you using php mailer or smpt connetction to servage.net please

HELP ME! Make my day, bay. ^^

Testing here http://socialtab.it/app/myil/mailer.php

Comment: it'd going to make me mad :D

Comment: i confirm you should use port 25 or 465 `~# nmap smtp1.servage.net
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp   open     smtp
465/tcp  open     smtps`

Comment: thanks a lot Tarik, the port is find. Still remains Host and ssl/tsl/startssl

Comment: does simply using mail() work?

Comment: i can access folders but i cant send...maybe servage have some whitelist to send?

Comment: when i use mail() the email goes simply to spam :D i prefer smtp ... i was an big fan of that function until 3 days ago

Comment: You are using `$mail->Port` but your object is `$msg`.

Comment: Thanks for help bros but i going to sleep...now it's 32h than i cant sleep xD i hate irresolved problems. I will check tomorrow, Sorry

Comment: Let me try Tarik, so you mean: $mail->Port = 25;

Comment: Also, make sure php_openssl is activated in your php conf. And/or you can first try without SSL.

Comment: tarik sorry but i new to smtp but how it possibile without ssl, with Pop?

Comment: I posted code on the link http://socialtab.it/app/myil/mailer.php

Comment: I really sorry but i cant take anymore |-) my hope is to dream some magic code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use port 2525 provably the defualt 25 is blocket at yout hosting, try to contact them.